# Error while trying to save object to MongoDB using mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So I'm trying to save a POST request on /api/register on the MongoDB DBMS using Mongoose node.js + express.

My schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const obSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    ID: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    description: { 
    type: String, 
    required: true
    },
    active: Boolean
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("OB", obSchema);
```

My code:

```
<express imports etc>
const OB = require('./models/ob.js');
app.post('/api/register', apiLimiter, async function (req, res){
  try  {
    OB.save(function (err) {
      if (err) return console.error(err);
      console.log("Saved successfully");
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send()
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

My error:

`TypeError: OB.save is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TypeError: OB.save is not a function

because you are operating on the raw Mongoose model and not an instance of a model.

The `save` function belongs to instances of Mongoose models, and in order to save a document in Mongo you must first instantiate a model:

```
const myOb = new OB({ ID: 1234, description: 'qwerty', active: true });

myOb.save((err) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log("Saved successfully");
});
```

[Mongoose model documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html)

Answer (score 0):

OB is not a function
You can try this.

```
const ob =new OB(data to be saved);

try{
await ob.save();
}
catch(e){
console.log(e)
}
```